# Call Python method through Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am trying to call a simple python method through JavaScript. But I am not able to call that method. Here is my code of Python:

```
def main():
    return   "Hello from Python"
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
function call() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/gadget/call.py",
        success: callbackFunc
    });
}

function callbackFunc(response) {
    console.log(response);
}
</script>
```

My ajax function reads the python file as text file and return the complete text of that file. It does not execute python method.

If someone have any idea to call a python file through JavaScript. Please help me on it.

Thanks

Comment: Unclear: Do you want to run the python code on the server or client?

Comment: If you want to execute it as a cgi script, you'll have to set your web server accordingly.

Comment: I am developing a gmail gadget. So I have to call my pyhton file from the gadget file. In gadget I can only write Javascript. And my python code will be in server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a REST API (such as flask) in python, and then the javascript will call this API using ajax- and then, the flask server will execute your python code.
More about flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/.
Enjoy!